# How can i identify a color of a pixel in a photo in delphi?

Tags: delphi, colors, pixel, photo

I want to know if it is possible to identify the color of every pixel, and the coordinates of the pixel in an image. In other words  i want to see how many pixels are for instance blue, and exactly where on the photo. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are 'tons' of questions/answers dealing with pixels on SO. Enter `delphi pixels` or `delphi scanline` in the search box. Sort the results on votes.

Comment: I guess you'll also need to define what you mean by blue. Working out the RGB value for each pixel is easy enough. The fun starts after that.

Answer (score 4):

Assign your photo to a `TBitmap` (if it is in another format).

Scan through every pixel of the bitmap using its `Canvas.Pixels` property (very slow way, but simple to use) or its `Scanline` property (very fast way, but more complicated to use).

Compare each pixel's RGB color value with your desired blue color value.  When you find a matching pixel, you will know its X/Y offsets within the `Pixels`/`Scanline` property.

Comment: Thanks allot will do